# express post receive json isn`t I send

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, request

I use request to send a json data to my express server.

But express receive the data isn`t my json.

I will show my code about this question.

#### The json I send

```
    {
            'commodityList': [
                {
                    'commodityName': 'aaa',
                    'commodityId': '2',
                    'commodityPrice': 128,
                    'commodityNumber': 2
                },
                {
                    'commodityName': '',
                    'commodityId': '1',
                    'commodityPrice': 59,
                    'commodityNumber': 10
                }
            ],
            'purchasePrice': 846,
            'userId': '1'
 }
```

#### The json I receive

```
{ 'commodityList[0][commodityName]': 'aaa',
  'commodityList[0][commodityId]': '2',
  'commodityList[0][commodityPrice]': '128',
  'commodityList[0][commodityNumber]': '2',
  'commodityList[1][commodityName]': 'bbb',
  'commodityList[1][commodityId]': '1',
  'commodityList[1][commodityPrice]': '59',
  'commodityList[1][commodityNumber]': '10',
  purchasePrice: '846',
  userId: '1' }
```

### The Code

#### The request

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/commodityManage/purchaseAdd',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    form: {
        'commodityList': [
            {
                'commodityName': 'aaa',
                'commodityId': '2',
                'commodityPrice': 128,
                'commodityNumber': 2
            },
            {
                'commodityName': 'bbb',
                'commodityId': '1',
                'commodityPrice': 59,
                'commodityNumber': 10
            }
        ],
        'purchasePrice': 846,
        'userId': '1'
    }
};

console.log(options.form.commodityList);

console.log(options.form.commodityList.length);

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var info = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("info:", info);
    }
}

request.post(options, callback);
```

#### The express

```
router.post('/purchaseAdd', function(req, res, next) {
    var uploadData = req.body;
    console.log(uploadData);
}
```

I didn`t know how to post json what I want.

Help me,please.
(´･_･`)

My express version is v4

My node version is v4.2.4

Comment: I use bodyParser can solve it.Thank you very much~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

> *The json I send*

A [JavaScript Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) isn't JSON, despite the similarities in their syntax.

JSON is a text format for representing structured data. It however isn't code.

---

If you'd like to send a JavaScript Object written out as JSON, you can use [`request`'s `json` option](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback):

```
var options = {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/commodityManage/purchaseAdd',
    headers: {
        // ...
    },
    json: { // <----
        'commodityList': [
            {
                'commodityName': 'aaa',
                'commodityId': '2',
                'commodityPrice': 128,
                'commodityNumber': 2
            },
            {
                'commodityName': 'bbb',
                'commodityId': '1',
                'commodityPrice': 59,
                'commodityNumber': 10
            }
        ],
        'purchasePrice': 846,
        'userId': '1'
    }
};
```

This will write out the data in the object as:

```
{"commodityList":[{"commodityName":"aaa","commodityId":"2",...
```

---

By using the `form` option instead, the object is serialized as [URL-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), formatted for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

```
// key1=value&key2=value&...    
commodityList%5B0%5D%5BcommodityName%5D=aaa&commodityList%5B0%5D%5BcommodityId%5D=2&...
```

Answer (score 0):

The json your receiving is the json that is being sent.  It's just being displayed in a different format.

To prove it try doing something like this:

```
router.post('/purchaseAdd', function(req, res, next) {

    //this will transform the object to a string so you can see all the keys/values
    var uploadData = JSON.stringify(req.body);

    console.log(uploadData);
}
```

Comment: sorry, this method isn`t work.But I use bodyParser can solve it.Thank you for my qusetion.lol

Answer (score 0):

I set the bodyParser in app.js to true

like this

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: 'lmb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```